# Just curious, why did my answer get labeled as community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I posted a solution to a question [How to mimic the behavior of `\ncput*` but without the unwanted opaque effect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97741/22413) which got labeled as a community wiki.  I was curious why?  And what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's due to your >10 edits. I've already pinged the mods about it.

Meta.SO reference

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

Comment: was that bad of me to edit it so many times?  Should I be more careful in posting my answers?

Comment: @A.Ellett Not really. But we would appreciate if you can make it to bare minimum. Because it gets bumped up in the frontpage. It's really not a problem at all. But for your own rep points you might want to avoid it. I've added a reference.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Further to what percuße said, bumping up is the whole reason this (still controversial) feature was introduced.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits/343#343

Comment: @CharlesStewart, I guess I should be more careful in how I post and edit my answers.  I didn't realize that edits were flagged or anything else.

Comment: @CharlesStewart is there a way to edit a post (such as your own answer) and not have it show up in the front page?

Comment: @A.Ellett: Comments can't be edited, except by the commenter within 2 (I think) minutes, and all edits to answers or questions (including question tags) cause the question to be bumped.

Comment: @A.Ellett No worries. Just keep in mind that more than 10 is high and needs extra attention to make it unCW. Other than that you are welcome to do whatever you want with your posts.

Comment: That happened to me once.  How does one un-wiki an answer?